# Cucumber with selenium opens several browsers

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

Can somebody help me to figure out why each time I run a feature with cucumber it opens 4 browsers? Whatever the number of scenario of my feature or the number of steps, when I execute the test script with cucumber 4 firefox browsers are opened.

Here is my conf :

- Ruby version : ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
- cucumber version : 1.3.18
- capybara version : 2.4.4
- selenium version : 2.44.0
- Firefox version : 33.0

Here is the content of env.rb in support folder :

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was because I had several files xxx_steps.rb in step_defintions folder and in each xxx_steps.rb I had "require 'watir-webdriver'"

So each time cucumber met require 'watir-webdriver' it opened a new browser.

Answer (score 0):

In java we use a @Before and then just tag the first scenario with it (@setup):

```
@Before("@setup") public void setUp() {
        driver = utilities.DriverFactory.createDriver(browserType);
```